# What does `apt-get install` do in the way of waiting for internet connection?

Tags: apt

I've got a really weird problem. I'm extending an [OS installer for the Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/FooDeas/raspberrypi-ua-netinst). I configure it to auto-boot after the installer does its stuff and run my script which does remaining installation. But sometimes I want to re-install my additions without reinstalling the entire OS. So I have a script called ***on-first-login.sh*** with something like this:

```
if [ $(command -v git) ]; then
    echo "Git already installed."
else
    apt-get install git -y
fi

git clone git@github.com:me/my-repo.git ~/my-repo
```

Now here's the really weird part. The above only works when git needs to be installed, or if I change the script to this:

```
apt-get install git -y

git clone git@github.com:me/my-repo.git ~/my-repo
```

Otherwise I get this error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known

I really want to solve this, mainly out of principle, but also to avoid calling `apt-get install git -y` because it takes about 5 seconds (if git's already installed) which is a bit of a pain.

I have tried making the script wait for a successful ping like so:

```
if [ $(command -v git) ]; then
    echo "Git already installed."
else
    apt-get install git -y
fi

pingerr=1
while [ $pingerr ]; do
    sleep 1
    ping -c 1 github.com | grep "1 received"
    pingerr=$?
    if [ $pingerr ]; then
      echo "Could not ping github. Retrying..."
    else
      echo "Successfully pinged github"
    fi
done

git clone git@github.com:me/my-repo.git ~/my-repo
```

But it just retries indefinitely.

What on earth is going on? It seems `apt-get install` is doing something special, and I'd love to know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already figured out, your `git clone` gets called before your network connection is fully up. The only magic that `apt-get` probably does is that it takes a little while to query the local package database. This is giving network just enough time to be enabled and configured.

The reason why your second script does not behave properly is because you are confusing program return codes. In bash, or shell in general, number zero represents TRUE boolean value. A program that exits successfully should return number zero. Thus if your ping (and grep) succeed, you get zero return value and `while 0` will loop forever.

Futhermore you're grabbing return value of the grep command instead of conveniently using ping directly. Try this script instead:

```
retries=0
while ! ping -c1 github.com >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    sleep 1
    if (( retries++ > 10 )); then
        echo "Max retries reached, aborting." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

git clone git@github.com:me/my-repo.git ~/my-repo
```

To increase verbosity, remove the output redirection from ping.

I guess this is obvious warning, but security of your setup looks suspicious - you're automatically downloading things from git with root account...

Comment: Excellent, thanks - will investigate. And thanks for pointer on security. It's of no importance right now but wise to be aware of for future use. Great answer - thank you